# array to objects in a react.js form

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, dictionary

I have a form code that the api is a PUT method, I have a part where I have to send it in the form of a objects, but when I send it it sends it to me as an array, they also tell me that I have to send them if it is true or false

[image]

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    const {
      state,
      city,
      mild_symptoms = [],
       } = event

    const YES = "Si"
      console.log(event)

    try {
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      const url =
        "XXXXXXXXX";
      myHeaders.append(
        "x-api-key",
        "XXXXX"
      );

      myHeaders.append("state", state);
      myHeaders.append("city", city);
      myHeaders.append(
        "mild_symptoms",
        `{"flu_syndrome": ${mild_symptoms.includes("flu_syndrome")}, "conjunctivitis": ${mild_symptoms.includes("conjunctivitis")}, "muscle_pain": ${mild_symptoms.includes("muscle_pain")}}`
      );
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: "cors"
      };
      const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
      console.log("FIRST RESPONSE ", response);
      const result = await response.text();
      console.log("RESULT", result);
      Modal.success({
        title: "Éxito",
        content: "Datos enviados correctamente",
        onOk: ()=>{
          window.location.href = "https://covid19.gob.sv/orientaciones-tecnicas/"
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR", error);
    }
```

I have to send this as a objects and not as an array

```
"mild_symptoms",
        `{"flu_syndrome": ${mild_symptoms.includes("flu_syndrome")}, "conjunctivitis": ${mild_symptoms.includes("conjunctivitis")}, "muscle_pain": ${mild_symptoms.includes("muscle_pain")}}`
      );
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing dictionary braces with list braces?

Comment: no, what are the list keys?